# Не получается выровнять по высоте таблицу внутри блока. Как это сделать?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Привет.

Как выровнять по высоте (middle) таблицу внутри блока?

Вот код:

```html
<html>
 <head>

  <style>
   *{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #div4{
    background-color:red;
    height:300px;
   }
   
   #table1{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div id="div4">
   <table id="table1">
    <tr>
     <td id="td1"><img id="girl" src="images/girl.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Почему назначение таблице *display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;* не срабатывает? С картинками и другими строчными элементами это работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;` выравниваются относительно друг друга. Т.е. если бы был еще один элемент с такими свойствами рядом с таблицей, то она бы выровнялась.

Можно воспользоваться псевдоэлементом :before (и только им) для обертки `#div4`.

```
#div4:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#div4{
  background-color:red;
  height:300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#div4:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#table1{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="div4">
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td id="td1"><img id="girl" src="images/girl.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. я с таким не сталкивался. можешь статью скинуть, где про это пишут?

Comment: Что значит "Можно воспользоваться псевдоэлементом :before для обертки #div4"? насколько я понимаю, этот псевдо элемент ставится ПЕРЕД #div4 и не содержит (не оборачивает) в себе #div4.

Comment: Я имела ввиду `#div4:before` эту запись

Answer (score 1):

я обычно использую обертку.

css:

```
.block{
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    background:black;
}

.wrap{
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.any_in_td{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

table{
    margin:auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="wrap">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="any_in_td"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. можешь статью скинуть, где про это пишут?

Comment: @Dimon [Вот про центрирование](http://learn.javascript.ru/css-center)